# How can I use XCGLogger in a mixed Xcode project (Objective-C and Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcglogger

I have a mixed Xcode project. My appDelegate is written in Objective-C and my Controller partly in Swift.
Is it possible to use XCGLogger in that project? If yes, how can I initialized the XCGLogger in the appDelegate (e.g. `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`)?

Answer (score 0):

I found and had the same issue too, wanting to incorporate in a mixed Swift+Objective-C project. Fortunately, I found this PR https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger/pull/122 that helps with a solution.

But in order to [check out his PR](https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger/pull/122/commits/00720fa6dd4d1a479663b1110c6d6c973b3c7a48) we need to make some change:

```swift
@objc public class XCGLogWrapper: NSObject {
    @objc public static func log(_ level: LogLevel = LogLevel.debug, functionName: String = #function, fileName: String = #file, lineNumber: Int = #line, logMessage: String) {}
```

**notice the omission of `level` label argument.**

===

**Explanation:**

so from this static function of `XCGLogWrapper`:

```swift
static XCGLogWrapper.log(_:functionName:fileName:lineNumber:logMessage:)
```

will be translated to this in Objective-C:

```c
[XCGLogWrapper log:level functionName: @(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) fileName: @__FILE__ lineNumber: __LINE__ logMessage: message ]
```

===

For more complete answer, check my comment on the PR https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger/pull/122#issuecomment-468136786

Hope it helps!